# Executing SQL script through transactions over multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

We are trying to implement a program which patches client software - Initially a .SQL will be run but if the script fails at any point we will rollback the database and stop the client DLL import process from working.

Our SQL scripts have "GO" statements and therefore we couldn't put together a nifty stored procedure for using `sp_executesql` as this doesn't allow the "GO" - Instead if we have a SQL Script which looks like this:

```
USE [SomeDatabase]

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
IF ( OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ProcedureToUpdate]') IS NOT NULL ) 
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureToUpdate]
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
    AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
    ROLLBACK TRAN
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 
    BEGIN
        --Flag that the procedure hasn't been dropped, begin another transaction
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
    END
GO

PRINT 'Creating procedure'
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureToUpdate]
AS 
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [dbo].[SomeTable] st
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[AnotherTable] at ON st.PK = at.fk

GO

IF @@ERROR <> 0
    AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
    ROLLBACK TRAN
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 
    BEGIN
        --Flag that the procedure hasn't been created, begin another transaction
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
    END
GO
```

We are then executing each "action" (split by the go statements) within a transaction in .NET for the Database in question - this will rollback a database if anything inside the loop fails.

```
  Using con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = con.BeginTransaction("Upgrade")
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.Transaction = transaction
    Try
      For Each transactionalScript In transactionalScripts
        cmd.CommandText = transactionalScript
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      Next
      transaction.Commit()
    Catch ex As Exception
      Log(String.Format("{0} : Script Failed", DateTime.Now.ToString()))
      Log(String.Format("{0} : Reason: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), ex.Message))
      transaction.Rollback("Upgrade")
      Log(String.Format("{0} : Database rolled back", DateTime.Now.ToString()))
    End Try
  End Using
```

Finally - here is my question. We need to handle up to 4 .SQL scripts which will each be for a different Database on a single server. Should any of the 4 scripts fail, we should rollback EVERY database which the scripts have affected - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).

If you use multiple connections within a `TransactionScope` then a distributed transaction is enlisted. This has it's own requirements (such as DTC), but that's certainly where you'd want to start looking.